# how to specify different css for ie

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I need to include different .css files for IE anf all other browsers.

I tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css">
<!--<![end if]-->
<!--[if IE]><!-->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style_IE.css">
<!--<![end if]-->
```

Comment: u should add the version for ie for example as !IE6

Comment: Note that conditional comments don't work for IE10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give css path this way for IE condition.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style_IE.css">
<![endif]-->
 <!--[if !IE]> -->
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

You can get better help from below link.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Enajoy...!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good page that gives a great list of examples for what you are looking for:

[ie only stylesheet](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Target ALL VERSIONS of IE

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="all-ie-only.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target everything EXCEPT IE

```
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="not-ie.css" />
 <!--<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7.css">
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 ONLY

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 6 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie6-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and LOWER

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 7 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 6]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie7-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Target IE 8 and HIGHER

```
<!--[if gt IE 7]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-up.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Please provide code, and examples. If that link breaks in the future, your answer won't have any function.

Comment: Thank you for posting some of Chris' code, however you copy/pasted a lot of unnecessary stuff too. The OP only wants to know how to target IE - not every specific version of IE :)

Comment: I know but it can also be a good reference for people that are looking for a version of IE also

Comment: Rather than posting it all here, couldn't you simply tell them the format? For instance: `[if IE <version number>]`. This way we don't have to have redundant code for 5, 5.5, 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Answer (score 1):

Check this
[About conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Example:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<p>Welcome to Internet Explorer.</p>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Should also include the *everything but* conditional comment too: `<![if !IE]>Not IE<![endif]>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed /> at the end of your link elements

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens when try it like this?

```
<!--[if !IE]> -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css">
<!-- <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE]> -->
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style_IE.css">
<!-- <![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got several errors defining the conditional comments:

```
<!--[if !IE]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE]>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_style_IE.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

This should do the trick.