# Is it possible to use different css for IE(any version of ie) and chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

Is it possible to use different css selector for IE(any version of ie) and chrome? Its a normal top property which appears differently in both browser and needs to explicitly adjusted according to the browser

Comment: Yes it is normal... yeeh welcome to the front end world.

Comment: Although you should have researched more, IE 10 and 11 actually don't support conditional comments anymore. That said, can you provide code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to specify different css for ie](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16279772/how-to-specify-different-css-for-ie)

Comment: I did a search and ie9 and above and chrome have almost same specificity but still the elements appear differently in both the browsers.

I am testing my page on IE11 and chrome

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve?

- If you want to compensate browsers all differences you can use for eg. modernizr
- If you want to add special css file for IE you can use Conditional comments They look like this:

  < !--[if IE 9]>
  < link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" th:href="ie9.csss"/>
  < ![endif]-->"
- If you want to fix something in css selector you can use hack(HACK! means not recommended, avoid but if you really have to and you have gun next to your head etc...) which will make properties or css class understandable only for specific browser (google this there is to many of them) eg. http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-how-to-target-ie6-ie7-and-ie8-uniquely-with-4-characters--net-10575
- And last option learn CSS and find where you made mistake because probably some element is diffrent size and that caused 1-2 px difference with position top

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in CSS alone. You need what are called "conditional comments" like the following:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<p>This is IE 8</p>
<![endif]-->
```

These are added to your HTML and can be used in many ways. Two primary ways that I have used them are:

- To link to a wholly different CSS style sheet
- To change the class on the `<html>` or some other parent tag and use CSS rules to select any children of it

I realize that second description may sound a bit complex but it's actually pretty simple so here's an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html lang="en-US" class="ie8">
<![endif]-->
<![if !IE]>
<html lang="en-US">
<![endif]>
...
<body>
    <div class="someClass"></div>
</body>
...
```

Then, in your CSS, use a selector like: `.ie8 .someClass`

Comment: A CSS reset is also an option to help make the playing field a little more even across browsers. This is a style sheet that you use to set default values for elements. There are many to be found online that you are free to use.

Comment: I am testing my page on ie11 and chrome

Comment: They consider ie10/ie11 industry compliant and so have not provided conditional CSS mentioned in your answer for these browsers

Comment: @user74046 provide code. You want to support ie10 and ie11 and there have to be bug in css that is causing this.

Comment: @user74046, Please see my comment about using a CSS reset. I think it may fix whatever issue it is that you are running into.

Comment: I tried using css reset, but even they dont seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the club! Anyways, although you can try to set browser specific css on elements, actually you cannot *guarantee* that it'll work *exactly* like you aimed. Because it depends on how those browsers handles these css classes, and there is nothing you can do about that. You may try to set different css classes for IE like this:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <html class="ie">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (!IE) | (IE 9)]><!-->
   <html>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

Notice that these are actually comment lines, but ie reads these lines and set the user-defined css class "ie" to html element (you may notice that Chrome and Firefox ignores these statements). you can then use this css, for example;

```
html.ie div{
    top: 0;
}
```

It's really annoying to deal with these cross-browser ie bs, I know. hope this helps

Comment: I am testing my page on ie11 and chrome

Comment: then you can use
<!--[if IE]>
   <html class="ie">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (!IE) ><!-->
   <html>
<!--<![endif]-->

Comment: They consider ie10/ie11 industry compliant and so have not provided conditional CSS mentioned in your answer for these browsers

Comment: oh, sorry. i thought i had ie8, but somehow it's updated to 11. it worked fine on mine. you can always tell ie to emulate ie9 if you want, by putting this in your head: <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

Comment: and this link may prove useful about feature detection, instead of browser detection https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ie/hh273397.aspx

Comment: @EmreTürkiş horrible advice "you can always tell ie to emulate ie9 i" WHY??? o God why?

Comment: i'm merely trying to find a workaround for his problem. so if you can provide why it's horrible, you'll have my thanks. I'm always eager to learn